# Memory defrag in Windows 10 for virtual machine hosting

Tags: windows, memory-management

I have a very legitimate reason to want to defrag the memory - I need to run a virtual machine that requires 2GB of memory. Unfortunately it requires that to be one continuous block in physical memory.

When trying to search for some tool that does this all that comes up is "RAM defrag is a scam", "useless" etc. I just used ramrush to get the desired effect however the gui of it is rather annoying.

Are there any built-in means to force Windows to release caches or actively page existing processes so that the physical memory is freed up for the virtual machine?

Comment: You might try installing a 2 GB RAMDisk, such as IMDisk, to start on booting, in the hope that it will keep its memory contiguous. Then drop the RAMDisk and immediately start the VM. Hope this helps.